# How to create HTML table in four columns using JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have an HTML table which I am rendering with `JSON` data, according to My requirement I have to show Data in 4 columns what ever the size of data is

**Issue**

when my data.length is equally divided by 4 then it is showing two rows of four columns, But when it length is 6 then it is showing two rows of 3-3 columns which is not correct, If i have data having length of 5 then it is showing only 4 Items not the fifth one, I don't know what blunder I am making

**My code**

```js
var tableValue = [{
  "Item Name": "JACK DANIELS 30",
  "Quantity": 292
}, {
  "Item Name": "JACK DANIELS 750",
  "Quantity": 731
}, {
  "Item Name": "JAMESON 30",
  "Quantity": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "JAMESON 750",
  "Quantity": 49
}, {
  "Item Name": "JIM BEAM WHITE 750",
  "Quantity": 409
}]

function addTable(tableValue) {
  var $tbl = $("<table />", {
      "class": "table table-striped table-bordered table-hover "
    }),

    $tb = $("<tbody/>"),
    $trh = $("<tr/>");


  var split = Math.round(tableValue.length / 4); // here i Think some issue
  console.log(split)
  for (i = 0; i < split; i++) {
    $tr = $("<tr/>", {
      "class": "filterData"
    });
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      $.each(tableValue[split * j + i], function(key, value) {

        $("<td/>", {
          "class": "text-left color" + (j + 1)
        }).html(value).appendTo($tr);

      });
    }
    $tr.appendTo($tb);
  }
  $tbl.append($tb);
  $("#DisplayTable").html($tbl);


}
addTable(tableValue);
```

```css
.color1 {
  background: #4AD184;
}

.color2 {
  background: #EA69EF;
}

.color3 {
  background: #E1A558;
}

.color4 {
  background: #F4F065;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="DisplayTable"></div>
```

Here In my JSON I have total `Items` but it is showing only 4, I have commented the line where I think issue is in my Code

Comment: First I see, do not use `round`, but `Math.ceil()` instead... other thing... well better create plain html code, than append... one more: in case total items `%4` is not zero, than you need to add more cells... good luck.

Comment: @skobaljic you are saying to change my approach, and right new code?

Comment: Well, I would do it other way, but you can do it however you like.

Comment: @skobaljic I am not getting the Idea I have done so many things in addition to this, so can't change the code :(

Comment: Can draw us a picture of what you are trying to achieve? It's hard to tell without visual representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first loop runs 1 times less than you want it to, and I'm not sure how your second loop works. Change it to :

```
    for (i = 0; i <= split; i++) { // changed this
      $tr = $("<tr/>", {
        "class": "filterData"
      });
      for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) { 
        $.each(tableValue[(i*4) + j], function(key, value) { // changed this
            console.log(j)
          $("<td/>", {
            "class": "text-left color" + (j + 1)
          }).html(value).appendTo($tr);

        });
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make it simple and do it this way:

```js
var tableValue = [{
    "Item Name": "JACK DANIELS 30",
    "Quantity": 292
}, {
    "Item Name": "JACK DANIELS 750",
    "Quantity": 731
}, {
    "Item Name": "JAMESON 30",
    "Quantity": 202
}, {
    "Item Name": "JAMESON 750",
    "Quantity": 49
}, {
    "Item Name": "JIM BEAM WHITE 750",
    "Quantity": 409
}]

function addTable(data, columns = 4, container = "#DisplayTable") {
    var tableHtml = '';
    tableHtml += '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">';
    tableHtml += ' <tbody>';

    var totalRows = Math.ceil(data.length / columns);
    for (let i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
        tableHtml += '  <tr>';
        for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            let dataIndex = i * columns + j;
            if (typeof data[dataIndex] != 'undefined') {
                tableHtml += '  <td class="text-left color' + (j + 1) + '">' + data[dataIndex]["Item Name"] + '</td>';
                tableHtml += '  <td class="text-left color' + (j + 1) + '">' + data[dataIndex]["Quantity"] + '</td>';
            } else {
                tableHtml += '  <td class="text-left color' + (j + 1) + '"></td>';
                tableHtml += '  <td class="text-left color' + (j + 1) + '"></td>';
            };
        };
        tableHtml += '  </tr>';
    };

    tableHtml += ' <tbody>';
    tableHtml += '</table>';
    $(container).html(tableHtml);
};
addTable(tableValue);
```

```css
.color1 {
    background: #4AD184;
}

.color2 {
    background: #EA69EF;
}

.color3 {
    background: #E1A558;
}

.color4 {
    background: #F4F065;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DisplayTable"></div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jabromp7/2/).

Comment: Same code for [2 or 3 columns](https://jsfiddle.net/jabromp7/3/). Please note, default javascript function parameters are [not compatible with IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

Each object within the array has 4 entries so to fill 4 columns each object will fill a row with the columns 1 and 3 having the keys and 2 and 4 for the values. Details are commented in demo.

```js
const data = [{
  "Item Name": "JACK DANIELS 30",
  "Quantity": 292
}, {
  "Item Name": "JACK DANIELS 750",
  "Quantity": 731
}, {
  "Item Name": "JAMESON 30",
  "Quantity": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "JAMESON 750",
  "Quantity": 49
}, {
  "Item Name": "JIM BEAM WHITE 750",
  "Quantity": 409
}];

/** genTable(selector, [...array]) 
@Param: selector [String]: element to append table to
        [...array][Array]: copy of the array of objeccts
*/
//A - Append htmlString of table to the given element
/*B - for...of loop of the given array by static method .entries()
      [index, object] destructed assignment allows easy access
      */
/*C - $('table')[0] is a jQ Object dereferenced to a jS Object
      in order to use the JS method .insertRow()
      */
//D - Same as B but with Object.entries() on each object of array
/*E - On each key/value  pair of current object .insertCell()
      and assign the text of each cell with the key then the value
      */
function genTable(selector, [...array]) {
  $(selector).append(`<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'><tbody></tbody></table>`); //A

  for (let [index, object] of array.entries()) { //B
    let row = $('table')[0].insertRow(); //C
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) { //D
      row.insertCell().textContent = key; //E
      row.insertCell().textContent = value; //E
    }
  }
}

genTable('main', [...data])
```

```css
tr td:first-of-type {
  background: #4AD184;
}

tr td:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: #EA69EF;
}

tr td:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: #E1A558;
}

tr td:last-of-type {
  background: #F4F065;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<main></main>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tableValue = [{
  "Item Name": "JACK DANIELS 30",
  "Quantity": 292
}, {
  "Item Name": "JACK DANIELS 750",
  "Quantity": 731
}, {
  "Item Name": "JAMESON 30",
  "Quantity": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "JAMESON 750",
  "Quantity": 49
}, {
  "Item Name": "JIM BEAM WHITE 750",
  "Quantity": 409
}, {
  "Item Name": "JAMESON 750",
  "Quantity": 49
}, {
  "Item Name": "JIM BEAM WHITE 750",
  "Quantity": 409
}]

function addTable(tableValue) {
   var  container =  $( "#DisplayTable" );     
   $.each(tableValue, function(key, value) {       
     
      var item = $('<div />', { 'class': 'item' }).appendTo(container);
      var Name = $('<div />', { 'text': value["Item Name"]}).appendTo(item);
       var Quantity = $('<div />', { 'text': value["Quantity"],'class':'count'}).appendTo(item);   
     
       
  });
    
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
 addTable(tableValue);
});
```

```css
#DisplayTable{

display:grid;
grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;



}
.item{
border:1px solid white;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
padding:10px;
border-radius:3px;
background:yellow;
color:#fff;
} 
.count{
font-weight:500;
font-size:3em;
}
.item:nth-child(4n-7) {
  background-color:green;
}

.item:nth-child(4n-6) {
  background-color:red;
}

.item:nth-child(4n-5) {
   background-color:blue;
}

.item:nth-child(4n-4) {
   background-color:black; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DisplayTable"></div>
```

Use Grid and flex instead of table. If you want to avoid Grid then use column-count. See the snippet.